# Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 “The network connection was lost.” - Occurs in iOS 9 with https

Tags: ios, ios9

The error logged (on iOS 9):

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 “The network connection was lost.”
```

It occurs frequently with `https://` request and with `http://` it works far more better, but still it throws error sometimes.

Is this error because of https call? Do we need to have http request for iOS 9 in order to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This usually means that your network connection dropped out while making the request... Do you have a good strong internet connection? Are you seeing issues when using other apps/programs?

Is this happening on the device or simulator? Try resetting the simulator or  restarting the device.

You aren't monitoring network traffic via a proxy are you? You can sometimes run into issues like this when SSL verification fails because for example you are monitoring network traffic via tools such as Charles.

Does the server you are talking with (https one) have a valid and trusted SSL certificate? Could be related to that too.

Comment: Thanks a ton for responding. Basically issue occurs in devices too and I have a very strong internet connection where others apps and live video streaming occurs properly.

And I have a Godaddy Shared Hosting with valid and trusted SSL Certificate and have been using AFNetworking library.

Comment: Maybe try checking out this issue on AFNetworking: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2801 ultimately its down to the way that requests are being made and the server config so it could be completely irrelevant but also could be quite useful (the second to bottom comment before it was closed)

Comment: Since I have a Shared Hosting Server I am not able to use 1 & 2 solutions and tried 3rd but issue still persists.